# How to run Docker inside Virtualbox (Ubuntu) and use it on Win10 host

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, virtualbox

i´m forced to use Win10 and Docker on my working PC. I like to set up a Virtualbox VM with Ubuntu and install docker on Ubuntu-VM. How can i map Docker from the VM to the Windows Host, run it in Ubuntu VM and use it on Win10 Host?

Thank you

Comment: What have you already tried?  How would you do this with other programs; if you had, say, a Python application in the VM but not in Docker, how would you work with it?  This overall approach is similar to what older Docker setups like Docker Machine or boot2docker do and you might look at those as well.

Comment: Hi, 

i did following steps:

1. Setup Ubuntu-Vm in Virtualbox on Win10 host
2. Installing and running Docker inside of Virtualbox 
3. Problem:  how to access the running Docker on Win host?

Answer (score 0):

This could be answered in https://serverfault.com/questions/225155/virtualbox-how-to-set-up-networking-so-both-host-and-guest-can-access-internet.

Another way that would come to my mind is using the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

But docker can also just run natively on a Windows host, which would save you the trouble.

Comment: Hi , 

thank you for your answer, i dont want to use Windows Subsystem. I like to run Docker in Ubuntu VM. I have a look at your link above.